# Wordpress: Converte specific Links in Backend-Editor with Link Tool

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am looking for a way to loop the links to be inserted beforehand and generate to a specific link. The links are recognized and converted based on their domain, I have already managed that. Unfortunately, I don't know how to insert a small button there and then send the selected link through the loop accordingly.

I don't know what is easier to implement:

1 possibility:
Link is converted directly when inserted
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGKR5.jpg)

2nd possibility
Links are inserted and then you click on them and you have a small field with the converter.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i36O4.jpg)

I thank you!